# Attach additional user info to Firebase push

Tags: node.js, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I have gotten the `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` to work on my React.js webapp with Firebase, but now want to attach additional information about the user when they signup other than their email and password (i.e. first name, last name, and phone). The current code attached is my logic so far, but doesn't work because I am think the `userId` I need to correspond with the other info isn't accessible yet.

What is the best way of going about adding additional user info to my push to firebase? Should I still use the `createUserWithEmailAndPassword`? I might need to create a container component to do the `writeUserData` function once the ID has been generated for the user in oauth.

**Register.js:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import fire from '../../config/Fire.js';
import { Link, withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import PasswordMask from 'react-password-mask';

class Register extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props)
      this.signup = this.signup.bind(this);
      this.writeUserData = this.writeUserData.bind(this);
      this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
      this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
      this.state = {
        first_name: 'Taylor',
        last_name: 'Doe',
        email: 'you@mail.com',
        phone: '1234567890',
        password: ''
      };
    }

    handleChange(e) {
        this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
    }

    handleSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }

    signup(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        // We want this directing else where, but am getting an error when done so
        fire.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.state.email, this.state.password).then((u)=>{ this.props.history.push('/about') }).catch((error) => {
            alert(error);
            });
    }

    writeUserData(userId, first_name, last_name, email, phone) {
        fire.database().ref('users/' + userId).set({
            userFirstName: first_name,
            userLastName: last_name,
            userEmail: email,
            userPhone : phone
        });
    }

    render() {
      return (
            <div className="m-container">
            <h1>Register</h1>
            <hr/>
            <div className="m-container">
                <form onSubmit={this.submitForm}>
                <label for="first-name">First Name: </label>
                <br/>
                <input 
                    onChange={this.handleChange} 
                    type="text" 
                    name="first_name" 
                    id="first-name" 
                    placeholder="Taylor"
                    />
                <br/>
                <label for="first-name">Last Name: </label>
                <br/>
                <input 
                    onChange={this.handleChange} 
                    type="text" 
                    name="last_name" 
                    id="last-name" 
                    placeholder="Doe"
                    />
                <br/>
                <label for="email">Email: </label>
                <br/>
                <input 
                    onChange={this.handleChange} 
                    type="text" 
                    name="email" 
                    id="email" 
                    placeholder="you@mail.com"
                    />
                <br/>
                <label for="phone">Phone: </label>
                <br/>
                <input 
                    onChange={this.handleChange} 
                    type="text" 
                    name="phone" 
                    id="phone" 
                    placeholder="1234567890"
                    />
                <br/>
                <div>
                    <label for="password">Password: </label>
                    <br/>
                    {/* Margin issue when showing and hiding password */}
                    <PasswordMask 
                    onChange={this.handleChange} 
                    type="password" 
                    name="password" 
                    id="password" 
                    placeholder="**********"
                    />
                </div>
                <br/>

                <button 
                    type="submit" 
                    className="m-btn" 
                    onClick={this.signup && this.writeUserData(this.user.id, this.first_name, this.last_name, this.email, this.phone)}>Register</button>
                &nbsp;
                <Link className="m-btn-inv" to="/login">Login</Link>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
        );
    }
  }

  export default withRouter(Register)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably are looking for a two-step process:

1. Create the new user
2. Write the additional information to the database

Since this is a two-step process, you want step 2 to only happen is step 1 is successful. So you should probably nest or chain the calls together. Something like this:

```
signup(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    // We want this directing else where, but am getting an error when done so
    fire.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.state.email, this.state.password)
      .then((u) => { 
        this.props.history.push('/about');
        writeUserData(u.user.uid, this.first_name, this.last_name, this.email, this.phone);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        alert(error);
      });
}

writeUserData(userId, first_name, last_name, email, phone) {
    fire.database().ref('users/' + userId).set({
        userFirstName: first_name,
        userLastName: last_name,
        userEmail: email,
        userPhone : phone
    });
}
```

And then wire it up in your button with:

```
<button 
    type="submit" 
    className="m-btn" 
    onClick={this.signup}>Register</button>
```

Comment: Gotcha, that makes sense. I am getting `'u' is not defined  no-undef` error now. Tried `this`, but then get `Cannot read property 'uid' of undefined`. Where's the `u` variable?

Comment: You declared that in your own code, in the the `then()`: `.then((u)=>{`. But I might have gotten the syntax wrong, so give `writeUserData(u.uid, ...` a try

Comment: Tried that, but it doesnt look like the `u` is in the scope of the `then` function because its outside the brackets/parenthesis

Comment: Ah, I see now. Fixed it in the answer.

Comment: Okay a bit further, got `Error: Reference.set failed: First argument contains undefined in property 'users.cxApXc3h9Pe0tyOlzvvYsae2AVp2.userFirstName'` now, but I believe it's because I don't have that 'table' in firebase, something like `this.database = fire.database().ref().child('users');` might help in constructor?

Comment: That means that `first_name`/`this.first_name` is `undefined`. Note that I just copied this from your original code.

Comment: My apologies, I am still new to React and Firebase. I think you helped me sufficiently, and will report back soon after a bit of research. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Alright I fixed it. I did need `this.database = fire.database().ref().child('users');` in the constructor, but I think what really fixed it was using `this.state.userFirstName` etc in the `writeUserData` function inside `signup` function. Thanks for the help!